# Reset all buttons after pressing the next button

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I need to change the image from the button to another after clicking on the button. I did this with the help of setBackgroundImage(). But how do I change the image of all buttons at once and change the image only to the button that is pressed...
![button set][1]

My viewController

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    self.tableView.separatorStyle = .none
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! UIT



        cell.TitleLabel.text=dataMas[indexPath.row]
        cell.name.text = titleTrack[indexPath.row]

        cell.btns.tag = indexPath.row

        cell.btns.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.PlayTrack(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside )







    return cell
}
```

and cell class

import UIKit

class UIT: UITableViewCell {

```
@IBOutlet weak var btns: UIButton!


@IBOutlet weak var TitleLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!




override func awakeFromNib() {

}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {

}
```

}

Comment: Could you provide more information??

Comment: @JeetendraKumar all the code I have is in class ViewController: UITableViewController.
There is also a class for working with cell - class UIT: UITableViewCell

Comment: All you need to do is make every button an instance property of the view controller and change their properties in the action methods of the buttons. If the user taps `button1`, in that button's action method, change whatever properties you want for `button2`, `button3`, so forth. There is nothing more to it.

Comment: @iabuseservers can you show me an example please?

Answer (score 1):

try this inside your ViewController.PlayTrack:

```
var numberOfButtons: Int = 5
@IBOutlet weak var btns: UIButton!

for i in 1...numberOfButtons {
    if btns.tag == i {
        // SET IMAGE TO BTN HERE.
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, it change button with clicked, but if i click next button, button before don't change default state